# More than 1 UIPickerView Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview

I was trying to make a simple app with 2 UIPickerViews and when I put in the second one, it just contains the same data as the first. I've declared the functions for inserting the data into the first one:

```
var typesOfData = ["KB","MB","GB"]
func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    return typesOfData.count
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String! {
    return typesOfData[row]
}
```

but I need to know how to declare these functions for the second UIPickerView.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the same delegate methods to populate both `UIPickerView`s. Just populate them conditionally depending on which `UIPickerView` you're dealing with. For example, if your first `UIPickerView`'s called `firstPickerView` and your second `UIPickerView` is populated by `secondDataSet`:

```
var typesOfData = ["KB","MB","GB"]
var secondDataSet = ["A","B","C"]
func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    if pickerView == firstPickerView {
        return typesOfData.count
    } else { // if it's the second picker view
        return secondDataSet.count
    }
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String! {
    if pickerView == firstPickerView {
        return typesOfData[row]
    } else {
        return secondDataSet[row]
    }
}
```